# Register a service and call after that

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, php-5.5

I have a problem with the service.
So my service is :

```
services:
    app.one_level_game:
        class: App\DesktopBundle\Lib\Game\OneLevel
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", %game_name%, %user_id% ]
```

My class OneLevel :

```
namespace App\DesktopBundle\Lib\Game;

use App\DesktopBundle\Entity\OnelevelHistory;
use App\DesktopBundle\Lib\DoctrineService;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;


class OneLevel{

protected $em;
/**
 * Constructor of application
 * @param $game_name
 * @param $user_id
 * @param $em
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $game_name, $user_id){
    $this->a_config     = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../../Resources/config/game.yml'));
    $this->game_name    = $game_name;
    $this->user_id      = $user_id;
    $this->score        = 0;
    $this->em           = $em;
}
```

After that I try to call :

```
$o_oneLevel = $this->get('app.one_level_game', $game_name, $user_id);
```

The error is : `The service "app.one_level_game" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "game_name".`
Can you help me please what I'm doing wrong ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Did you have a parameter named `game_name` in your parameter.yml (or equivalent) file ? Because here, you said to pass this parameter to the constructor of your class `OneLevel`

Comment: The `game_name` is get from formular

Answer (score 2):

If you have `%game_name%` in

```
services:
    app.one_level_game:
        class: App\DesktopBundle\Lib\Game\OneLevel
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", %game_name%, %user_id% ]
```

You should have `game_name` in `parameters.yml` (and `parameters.yml.dist`)

```
#paremeters.yml
    game_name: MyGameName
```

But if you want to pass parameters on call, you could pass the paremetrs throught the method call (solution 1) or set it through setter (solution 2)

**Solution #1**

```
$service = $this->get('app.one_level_game');
$service->doSomething($gameName, $userId);
```

This is easiest but if you do many call of your service you should pass always pass them to your service. In this case solution #2 is better

**Solution #2**

```
$service = $this->get('app.one_level_game');
$service->setGameName($gameName);
$service->setUserId($userId);

$service->doSomething();
```

and in OneLevel class

```
class OneLevel{

   protected $em;

   public function __construct(EntityManager $em){
       $this->a_config     = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../../Resources/config/game.yml'));
       $this->score        = 0;
       $this->em           = $em;
   }

   public function setGameName($gameName)
   {
        $this->gameName = $gameName;
   }

   public function setUserId($userId)
   {
        $this->userId = $userId;
   }
```

If those 2 solution are not sufficient you should review your code architecture

Comment: The `game_name` is get from formular. How to indicate this in the service ?

Comment: @user7424312 You are getting closer to understanding services though you should probably have responded to your previous question before moving on.  As goto is saying, you cannot pass additional parameters when requesting a service from the container.  I think what you will end up with is defining a game factory as a service then creating your games from it.